# Error in looped regression using prodest package. R

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression, economics

I have an unbalanced panel, and I am trying to run this regression to estimate a production function.

I know this regression has a bootstrap/iterative component.

This is the package and a data similar to mine:

```
library(prodest)

data(chilean)
```

This data is way too similar to mine, the only difference is in `chilean$idvar`, this data got a numeric id but my data (`base2$ruc`) got a string id and way more obs.

This is the code for the regression:

On Chilean data:

```
LP_model1 <- prodestLP(chilean$Y, 
                       fX = cbind(chilean$fX1, chilean$fX2),
                       sX = chilean$sX,
                       pX = chilean$pX, 
                       idvar = chilean$idvar,
                       timevar = chilean$timevar, 
                       R = 30)
```

And it works

This is for my data, all numerics, no missing values, just the difference in the idvar, and more columns that I don't use in this process.

```
levpet <- prodestLP(base2$c_y,
                    fX=base2$c_l,
                    sX=base2$c_k,
                    pX=base2$c_m,
                    idvar=base2$ruc,
                    timevar = base2$year,
                    R=30  )
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(42719L, 82109L, 82678L,  : 
  replacement has 469326 rows, data has 78221
```

My data has 78221 obs, while chilean dataset has 2544.

I don't understand what the error is saying or how to solve it.

Can anybody please help me with this one?

Thanks in advance.

---

This is an example using the chilean model:https://rpubs.com/hacamvan/319728

This is the package documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prodest/prodest.pdf

And here's what does my variables mean:

- `c_y` is log of value added
- `c_l` is log of wages
- `c_k` is log of capital
- `c_m` is log of materials
- `ruc` is the firm identifier (a string)
- `year` is a numeric.